Content Banner GD PHP library required. - Error when I upload a Banner on my Blog Posts in OctoberCMS
As it says in the title, it's a simple one. On the Admin Console, In the Blog section, under individual posts, I upload a Banner for a blog post and then when I click on to the post again (via Admin), it gives me a completely unstyled view of the page, with the message at the bottom of the page "Content
Banner GD PHP library required."
I have checked my php.ini and the gd extension is enabled. Everything works totally fine, before I upload the Banner.

Call phpinfo to verify the extension was actually loaded. It also shows in the top section, which php.ini was used, so make sure you edited the correct one. (And depending on your server setup, you might need to restart it, after making php.ini changes,)
